# mean and standard deviation in timeseries

Tags: time-series, data-analysis, mean, python-3.8, kalman-filter

I have a financial time series and I want to make a new dataset out of it . I want to take every 20 data point(rows) and replace them with one data points like this :

[mean of those 20 data points , standard deviation of those 20 data points].

I actually think I need gaussian model for the variation or the standard deviation.

and I use python 3.
my dataset is like the first column is the index(number of days) and the second column is the close prices

I do not know the code for taking every 20 data point and replace them with data I wrote above

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that this is not a pure Python forum, thus please always include the tag of the language you're programming in when asking a question here.

Answer (score 0):

If the data points are stored in a dataframe, say `df`, you could group them using [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/groupby.html) like this -

```
df.groupby(df.index / 20)
```

You could compute the [mean](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html) and [standard deviation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.std.html) of the groups as follows, and [concatenate](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) both of them if you need to.

```
df.groupby(df.index / 20).mean()
df.groupby(df.index / 20).std()
```